# Count div id appendTo another divide

Tags: javascript, appendto

I have some divides which are created in a jquery drag script.

This part of the script is for the div

```
for ( var i=0; i<52; i++ ) {
    $('<div><img src="card.png" onmouseover="this.src=&quot;images/card_' + numbers[i] + '.png&quot;" /></div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      snap: 'true',
      revert: true
    } );
  }
```

**Example of divides created**

```
<div class="ui-draggable" id="card7">
<img src="card.png" onmouseover="this.src=&quot;images/card_7.png&quot;">
</div>
<div class="ui-draggable" id="card18">
<img src="card.png" onmouseover="this.src=&quot;images/card_18.png&quot;">
</div>
```

If i look at the page source It doesn't display the div above, if I highlight the image and view selection source then i can see the div.

Each div is created with the id card+number, which is also the same number as the image used. There are 52 div altogether so the result I am looking for is 52.

This script below doesn't display anything, I have also tested with an alert just to check and it displayed 0.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var amount = $("#cardPile").children("div[id^=card]").length
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = amount;
</script>
<div id="total" style="color:#fff"></div>
```

I have also just tried counting the img tags of the div but also this is 0

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert($("#cardPile > img").length);
</script>
```

Comment: You're doing an awful lot here, what exactly is your question? You want to generate 52 divs with images that have draggable events attached to them? Do you have the div with the "cardpile" ID already on the page? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @Organiccat My question is how can i count the div elements #card+number which should display the result 52. These 52 div are appendTo another div #cardPile

Comment: Are there other divs that could be children of `$("#cardPile")`?  If not, then you could simply use `$("#cardPile").children();` (or `$("#cardPile").children("div");`, if you wanted to be specific about the element type).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add a class to your cards to help you identify them.  Try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dNwL6/).

```
$(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 52; i++ ) {
        $('<div />', { class: 'card' }).
            appendTo( $('#cardPile') ).
            draggable({
                revert: true
            });
    }

    console.log($('#cardPile').find('.card'));
});
```

Comment: I can identify each card from its div id #card+number, but no matter what i do I can't seem to be able to count the amount of div id's

Comment: Try adding [attribute queries](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) to the find method.